# How to add to an int in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, integer, int, addition

Seems like this should be about the simplest thing you could do with an int but I cant seem to find anything showing how to do it. Tried google but I get a million hits all of which are way more in depth than what im trying to understand.

What I want to do is have an integer and as something happens (button press, image moved, whatever) I want to add 1 to this integer and have a separate method, when its called,  check the integer and preform one of several actions depending on the value.

I know how to do all of this except add 1 to the int?

I know this must be a crazy stupid question for you guys, anybody care to throw me a bone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare int index in .h file

Now on click of button:

```
 -(void)btnClicked:(id)sender
 {
     index++;
 }
```

Any other method image moved then

```
index++;
```

Now perform action like this:

```
-(void)performAction:(int)index
{
   switch(index)
   {
      //make case depending on number
      case : 1
      {
          // do something here on index 1
      }
      break;
      .....
      .....
      .....
      default
      {
          // do something here if not that index 
      }
      break;

   }


}
```

Comment: Price, you rock  buddy! index++;  did it for me, I was trying to do index + 1;   also the switch part will help me clean up all the if statements I was planning to use. Thanks man!

Answer (score 2):

```
int i = 4;
i++;
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes it was exactly that, marked the above answer accepted as it will likely help someone more down the road but you nailed it

Answer (score 0):

You should add a NSUInteger property to the UIViewController where the actons that you want to count take place. Then as a first step of each action you can add 1 to that property.

```
@interface MyViewController extends UIViewController
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger actionCounter;
@end

@implementation MyViewController
@synthesize actionCounter;

//in your actions here, add one to actionCounter
-(void) IBAction doSomething{
    self.actionCounter++;

    //do the actual action here
}

//in your check method, read the actionCounter value and do something
-(void) checkActionCount{
    if(self.actionCounter => 1){
        NSLog(@"User did something");
    }
}

@end
```